# Room database no such table exception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

So I'm exporting database file to external storage before doing so I'm closing database, and after database is exported I want continue working with this closed database how do I reopen same database without restarting application? If I restart application everything works, but if I just restarting `MainActivity` where `getInstance()` method is called and trying to delete something from database app crashes and produces this exception:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: room_table_modification_log (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Note WHERE entryid = ?
```

Im closing database using `destroyInstance()` method:

```
companion object {
    private var INSTANCE: MyDatabase? = null

    var lock = Any()

    fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabase{
        synchronized(lock){
            if (INSTANCE == null){
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, MyDatabase::class.java,"MyDB.db").build()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }

    fun destroyInstance() {
        if (INSTANCE?.isOpen == true){
            INSTANCE?.close()
        }

        INSTANCE = null
    }
}
```

Comment: post your table entity class. As per your log, it says you dont have table called `Note`

Comment: Everything is fine with table I checked it and everything works it just happens because database file was imported and I need to restart app that it would work again because database is closed

Comment: I just don't know how to open database after it was closed

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Have you come across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421312/reopen-room-database/70147223#70147223