# Reopen ROOM database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to close and then reopen Room database. (The purpose is to backup SQLite file)

This is how I close it:

```
public static void destroyInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE != null && INSTANCE.isOpen()) {
        INSTANCE.close();
    }
    INSTANCE = null;
}
```

INSTANCE is a [RoomDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase) object

And to reopen I'm initializing INSTANCE object again by calling:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, C.ROOM_DB_NAME)
```

After I move to another activity, I'm seeing this error in logcat: `E/ROOM: Invalidation tracker is initialized twice`

SELECT queries work fine, but INSERT fails with the following errors:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: room_table_modification_log

E/ROOM: Cannot run invalidation tracker. Is the db closed?
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The database '/data/user/0/ro.example.example/databases/mi_room.db' is not open.
```

Although INSTANCE.isOpen() returns true

Room version: 1.1.1

Does anyone know what is with this "room_table_modification_log" table?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I'm still getting this error in Room 2.2.5.

Comment: No solution. I just don't close the DB anymore. If you want to copy the DB file to another location, you can check the answer below (schv09's answer)

Comment: @MickeyR Did you get any solution for that, I am also getting this error

Comment: Any solution for that @AlexBusuioc I am getting this error in version 2.3.0

Comment: No solution for reopening a previously closed room database. I'm just not closing the DB anymore. It might help to check @schv09's answer or this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987119/backup-room-database

Comment: @MuazzamA. This was the solution for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957123/room-db-file-import-error-no-such-table-room-table-modification-log/64054341#64054341

Answer (score 4):

For future readers: You don't need to close the database to copy the file to another location (create a backup).

The Android implementation for a SQLite database is normally in `WAL` [(write-ahead log)](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) mode. This uses 3 files in the background: The first with the name of your database (i.e. `my_db`, the second one with that name and the "-shm" suffix (`my_db-shm`) and the third one with the "-wal" suffix (`my_db-wal`). The `-wal` file will  save changes.

If you want to make a backup using the normal path for your database (`my_db` file), you need to make sure that it is up to date with the latest transactions. You do this by running a checkpoint on the database. After this, you can copy this file to the desired location on the phone and then keep using your database without issues. The accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987119/backup-room-database) explains it well:

> But if moving everything to the original database file is what you
>   want to do, then you don't have to close the database.
>
> You can force a
>   checkpoint using the `wal_checkpoint` pragma instead. Query the
>   following statement against the database. We use raw queries here
>   as `pragma` is not yet supported by Room (it will trigger a `UNKNOWN query type error`).
>
> Have this query inside of your DAO:

```
@RawQuery
int checkpoint(SupportSQLiteQuery supportSQLiteQuery);
```

> And then when you
>   call the checkpoint method, use the query then:

```
myDAO.checkpoint(new SimpleSQLiteQuery("pragma wal_checkpoint(full)"));
```

Comment: Great answer! But what will happen, if I want to clear current database after checkpoint and to copy database base file to storage? I use rxjava - and are there no guarantees, that some thread should not write something to database between 'checkpoint' and 'copying DB' functions, as result, I'm not sure, that I don't clean data which don't moved to storage. What do you think? Thank!

Comment: UPD: I think, I should be using this operations in beginTransaction() and endTransaction() block, without DAO, using raw 'query' (because DAO wrap everything in begin/endTransaction() - and it's not true in this situation), what do you thing, I'm right?

Comment: I'm sorry, dr_begemot, but I can't help you here since I don't use rxjava. I hope you find a solution soon!

Comment: @schv09 I know this is an old post, but is there a way to reset the database instance without having to close the app and reopen it? when I restore the database, all my flows are still using an old instance of the database and I have to close the open and remove it from recents and open it again to get the restored data.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your Room version to `1.1.1-rc1` and the problem will be gone. Keep an eye out on updates as this is a bug in 1.1.1

Comment: Just tested. Nope, this does not solve the issue. Exactly the same behaviour

Comment: I remember having the same issues. This post fixed the issue for me and other people https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370683/room-migration-no-such-table-room-table-modification-log

Comment: Indeed, these two issues seem to be related. The context in which they appear are different (close - reopen database in my case; database migration in the other post's case). Unfortunately, my issue manifests on all Room versions

Answer (score 0):

After spending so many days finally I found the solution to this, you need to create the table `room_table_modification_log` in `onOpen` Db callback.

Like below:

```
private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MainDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext,
                MainDatabase::class.java,
                databaseName
            ).addMigrations(MIGRATION_2_3)
                .addCallback(getCallback())
                .build()
        }
```

And implement the `getCallback()` function like this:

```
fun getCallback(): Callback {
    return object : Callback() {
        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
                db.execSQL("CREATE TEMP TABLE room_table_modification_log(table_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, invalidated INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)")          
            }
        }
}
```

After doing the above things you will not able to get the error `room_table_modification_log`